# Selecting Rows that only match the column values in another data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have a data frame:

```
>df_idbank.dtypes

DATASET                   object
IDBANK                    object
KEY                       object
FREQ                      object
INDICATEUR                object
CORRECTION_label_en       object
```

Etc.

I have another data frame:

```
>df_INDICATORS
    Label                                               IDBANK
0   Summary indicator of overall economic situatio...   1586891
1   Business climate summary indicator - SA series      1586890
2   Trend of expected activity - Overall - SA series    1586916
3   Trend of expected activity - Building structur...   1586885
4   Trend of expected activity - Finishings - SA s...   1586886
```

This would give a set of values pertaining to only values matching `IDBANK =="001586891"` from `df_idbank` data frame.

```
df_idbank = df_idbank.loc[(df_idbank.FREQ == "M") & (df_idbank.CORRECTION_label_en == "Seasonal adjusted") & (df_idbank.IDBANK =="001586891") ]
```

How do I select all the values matching `IDBANK` column in `df_INDICATORS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
df_idbank = df_idbank.loc[
    (df_idbank.FREQ == "M") & 
    (df_idbank.CORRECTION_label_en == "Seasonal adjusted") & 
    (df_idbank.IDBANK.isin(df_INDICATORS.IDBANK)) ]
```